# Solving aliasing problem in c++

Tags: c++, constructor, copy

I was trying following code in which I defined copy c'tor explicitly to solve aliasing problem.
But code is giving runtime error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

class word
{
  public:
    word(const char *s) // No default c'tor
    {
      str=const_cast<char*>(s); 
      cnt=strlen(s);
    }
    word(const word &w)
    {
      char *temp=new char[strlen(w.str)+1];
      strcpy(temp,w.str);
      str=temp;
      cnt=strlen(str);
    }
   ~word()
   {
     delete []str; 
     cout<<"destructor called"<<endl;
   } 
   friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os,const word &w);

 private:
   int cnt;
   char *str;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os,const word &w)
{
  os<<w.str<<" "<<w.cnt;
  return os;
}

word noun("happy");
void foo()
{
  word verb=noun;
  cout<<"inside foo()"<<endl;
  cout<<"noun : "<<noun<<endl<<"verb : "<<verb<<endl;
}

int main()
{
  cout<<"before foo()"<<endl<<"noun : "<<noun<<endl;
  foo();
  cout<<"after foo()"<<endl<<"noun : "<<noun<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Naveen has already shown you an error. Another one is that your class is missing an assignment operator. (Google for "Rule of Three".) Why do you do this anyway? __Why not use `std::string`?__

Comment: @glowcoder: It's not homework. I was reading Thinking in C++ in which a complex example was given. I was just trying to understand concept by making a small program.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem is in this constructor:

```
 word(const char *s) // No default c'tor
    {
      str=const_cast<char*>(s); 
      cnt=strlen(s);
    }
```

Here you are not allocating any memory to copy the string into `str` variable. But in destructor of the class you are doing `delete[] str;`, since the memory for the `str` is not allocated using `new[]` it is crashing. You need to allocate memory similar to one you are doing in copy constructor and copy the string into the newly allocated memory. Or better still, use `std::string`.

EDIT:
If you really don't want to use `std::string` for some reason, you also need an assignment operator with check for [self assignment](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/assignment-operators.html#faq-12.1) as mentioned by @icabod.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that there's no assignment operator, so in method "foo()" you would actually end up trying to delete the data pointed to by "noun" anyway. If playing with pointers in a class, you really need an "operator=" too.

Comment: @icabod.. Why do I need operator= because in foo(), I am creating a new object, not assigning to any previously constructed.

Comment: @Happy Mittal: You are not using it in this code, but that doesn't mean you won't use it tomorrow. When you are writing a class and you are writing a copy constructor to it, you *should* write a assignment operator also.

Comment: Rather than doing a test for self-assignment, use the [copy-and-swap idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom). That's much better in several ways.